# GUID is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 when posting to .net core endpoint from axios, react and typescript

Tags: typescript, axios, .net-6.0, guid, core-api

I have a .net endpoint here:

```c#
public class ListContactRequest
{
    public Guid userId { get; set; }
}

[Authorize]
[HttPost]
[Route("listContacts")]
public async Task<AddressBookListContacts> listContacts([FromBody]ListContactRequest req)
{
     return blah blah....
}
```

and my react axios calls in typescript

```ts
import { Guid } from "guid-typescript";

interface IListContactRequest {
  userId: Guid;
}
const ListContacts = (user: IListContactRequest) => {
  console.log(user);
  return axios
    .post(API_URL + "/listContacts", user, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data;
    });
};
```

the problem is that, when the axios method fires, it reaches the .net endpoint,however, the guid within the parameter object, is coming through as 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

when console logging the front end, the guid is appearing correctly, but when it hits the backend api, it seems to not carry over.

can someone offer some advice?

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(user))
```

shows

{"userId":{"value":"24883e12-439d-4e54-aae5-5b1d5140833e"}}

Comment: In your Axios request, use `data`, not `params`. The latter is for URL query parameters.

Comment: hey @Phil I changed this to  data: { user: user } in my axios.post but this is still doing the same thing, guid is still 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Comment: Try `data: user`. There's no need to nest the object in another. You could even make it much simpler... `axios.post(API_URL + "/listContacts", user)`

Comment: that doesnt seem to work either, infact the latter just comes in as 'null'

Comment: What does the `console.log(user)` show? Please also [edit] your question to match the current code

Comment: edited to reflect current version.  console log is showing  {userId: Guid}
userId
: 
Guid
value
: 
"24883e12-439d-4e54-aae5-5b1d5140833e"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

Comment: Where does the Typescript `Guid` type come from? Please [edit] your question to show **exactly** what the console log shows. You can also try `console.log(JSON.stringify(user))` to see exactly how it will be serialised for the request

Comment: hey@Phil please see edits, also the typescript guid edit, which comes from a npm package

Comment: Well there's your problem. The Guid isn't serialising to the JSON structure you need. Which NPM package does it come from? You could try `axios.post(url, { userId: user.userId.value })` but I don't know if that's available. Also, you don't need to set the content-type header; Axios does that for you automatically

Comment: that would make sense, although thats a blocker as I need a guid to talk to my backend. axios.post(url, { userId: user.userId.value }) isnt available to type guid. do you have any suggestions how i would do this?

Comment: You might be interested in this issue ~ https://github.com/snico-dev/guid-typescript/issues/19

Answer (score 0):

Your `Guid` is serialising to JSON as an object with `value` property but your C# model does not match.

You can use either the `Guid.prototype.toString()` or `Guid.prototype.toJSON()` methods to get the correct value

```ts
axios.post("/listContacts", {
  userId: user.userId.toJSON().value // or user.userId.toString()
}, {
  baseURL: API_URL
});
```

See https://github.com/snico-dev/guid-typescript#props-and-methods

---

Perhaps a neater option would be to make `IListContactRequest` a class instead that implements its own `toJSON()` method

```ts
class ListContactRequest {
  constructor(readonly userId: Guid) {}

  toJSON() {
    return {
      userId: this.userId.toJSON().value,
    };
  }
}

const user = new ListContactRequest(Guid.create());
axios.post(url, user);
```